# How to seperate public and authorized routes of the same resource?

Tags: rest, authentication, routes

What would be an appropriate routing for separating a public and an authenticated route which refers to same resource?

Assume that I have a user table, and an endpoint to retrieve the user info. In my app everyone can see the profile of any user. But I don't want email of the user to be public to other users. So I can't use single route with single handler.

I can think of 3 solutions:

1. Have 2 separate routes with 2 different handlers: `/user/{id}` for authenticated and `/public/user/{id}` for public.
2. Have 1 route with 2 different handlers, and execute the handler based on the authentication of the user.
3. Separate user table into 2 tables, one containing public information about the user, other containing private information, and have 2 routes, one to get public info, other to get private info.

I would love to hear which one is the right way to handle this situation and why. If you have any other solutions than these, I would love to hear about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

it depends I suggest to use separate microservice deployed on app server which server external users. Different table if less users or if the user volume is high make it separate instance of DB

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).